# The sentence is a headline for a digital ad and I'm not sure the tenses are correct

Tags: tenses

Since 1902, we are looking out for you.

Answer (score 1):

According to this source - https://www.ef.com/ca/english-resources/english-grammar/present-perfect-and/ - "since" can only be used with perfect tenses.

Since this is in the category of "actions or events that have been completed or have happened in a period of time up to now" (https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/present-perfect), you should use the present perfect. So:

"Since 1902, we have been looking out for you."

Or

"Since 1902, we have looked out for you."

I believe either would be grammatically correct. Good luck!

Comment: A common, though arguably ungrammatical, form for company slogans would give them "Looking out for you since 1902". Having said that, as it's a web page "Looking out for you since 19:02" might be more accurate :)

Answer (score 0):

Suppose this "looking out" is still happening today?  Why not use present tense then?

If you say "we have been looking out for you" it may suggest that the "looking out" has ended or may end at any time.

Comment: Plus, marketing material needs to be dynamic, another reason for present tense.